# How do you access the Main UI Thread in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-8

How do you access the Main UI Thread in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight?  I recently upgraded a rather large project from Windows Phone 8.0 to 8.1 Silverlight App.  Now everything runs on a worker Thread and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` no longer works.  Even when the app is launched using `Application_Launching` event it is on the Worker Thread, page navigation coming into the OnNavigateTo methods come in on the worker threads??

How do I access the Main UI Thread in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight?

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` no longer works.

`Dispatcher.RunAsync` does not exist only `InvokeAsync` and neither of these works just runs the code on a Worker thread.

```
var dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
await dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
  () => DoSomething());
```

Throws an unhandled exception and does not work.

Can anyone lend me any advice or tips in this matter???

Comment: What is the exception you receive? `dispatcher.RunAsync` looks good.

Comment: You're using the dispatcher of the current thread which obviously isn't the UI thread because if it were you wouldn't need it. Quick googling tells me System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher should work, but then I've never written silverlight before.

Comment: @Wosi The dispatcher gets initialized and is not null.  But when RunAsync is called it throws Unhandeld Exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} even though I wrapped the RunAsync line in a try catch it still threw the UnhandledExpcetion

Comment: @Voo  do you know why in WP 8.1 it doesnt start the App on the Main UI thread like in WP 8.0 ?? only has BeginInvoke and InvokeAsync, it does not have the method RunAsync.  If I use BeginInvoke it fires the action but does it on the Worker Thread still and not the Main UI Thread.  If I call InvokeAsync it does the same thing.